# Removing pop up menu items

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In the eclipse menu there is menu item File in that File menu there is a popup menu new->other so how can we remove that popup menu Other programmatically.

Comment: Look at the `org.eclipse.ui.activities` extension point.

Comment: I'd look at `org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters` extension point and then add it to `visibleWhen` of `command` in `menuContribution`